# Spring Data Autowiring: Two bean candidates using @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, repository

I have a UserRepository which is derived from a JPARepository using Spring Data:

```
@Transactional
@Repository( value = "userRepo")
@RepositoryDefinition( idClass = Integer.class , domainClass = info.frankmarx.model.User.class  )
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository< User , Integer > {

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED )
User findUserByUserName( String userName );

@Query( "select u from User u where u.isExpired = false and u.isDeleted = false and u.userName = ?1" )
User findActiveUserByName( String userName );

}
```

The repository is configured in my AppConfiguration-Class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(value = "info.frankmarx.repository" , entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory" , transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
@EnableVaadin
public class AppConfiguration {

@WebListener( )
public static class MyContextLoaderListener extends ContextLoaderListener {

}
...
}
```

And there is component-scan etc. in the applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="info.frankmarx"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

But when I want to autowire this Repository into a Service like this:

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
```

I always get the error message in Intellij already that there are TWO bean candidates and that I should use a qualifier annotation:

```
@Qualifier("userRepository")
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
```

If I use a qualifier then it works.

But I have no idea why it doesn't work without a @Qualifier.

I really have no idea what is going on.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure but you have used Respository with name and RepositoryDefination and i think either one is sufficient  for creating object. Annotating an interface with RepositoryDefinition will cause the same behaviour as extending Repository. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/RepositoryDefinition.html

Answer (score 0):

Generally the error `there are TWO bean candidates` occurs when you have defined 2 beans for same type and so at runtime spring needs a way to identify which bean you really want to autowire in this property,

for this we use annotation `@Qualifier` and in the parametr to this bean we need to provide the name of bean that we want to autowire.

Hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: But when I use Intellij to navigate to the two bean candidates it points me to the SAME bean and there is only ONE bean of that type in the whole Application.

Comment: The other bean candidate conflicting with UserRepository is SimpleJpaRepository which implements findOne(), findAll() and so on

Answer (score 0):

UserRepository interface should not be annotated, the other bean candidate in your case would be **SimpleJpaRepository** which is in conflict with your **UserRepository**.
It should be sufficient for you only extend spring Repository interface since you're enabling repositories via **@EnableJpaRepositories** annotation on your configuration class, so your repository would look like:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository< User , Integer > {

User findUserByUserName( String userName );

@Query( "select u from User u where u.isExpired = false and u.isDeleted = false and u.userName = ?1" )
User findActiveUserByName( String userName );

}
```

In the other hand, @Transactional should be used on the service method invoking your repository's insert(entity)/save(entity)/find()/delete(entity) method.

Comment: Thank you for answering! You are 90% right. After checking and some more reading I've found out, that you either use the `@RepositoryDefinition` if it NOT derived from one of the marker interfaces like JPARepository OR you derive YOUR repository from one of the marker interfaces and DON't use the `@RepositoryDefintion` because this really creates TWO Bean candidates of the same type - in my case UserRepository.